# Nomenclature duplicates

Tags: nomenclature

Is there a way to automatically remove duplicates from the generated Nomenclature?

E.g. adding multiple times:

```
\nomenclature{HTML}{HyperText Markup Language}
```

in your TeX file **should** generate **only one** entry in the Nomenclature.

This minimal example shows what happens:

```
% This is test.tex
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{nomencl}
\makenomenclature
\begin{document}

Some text \nomenclature{HTML}{HyperText Markup Language}

\newpage
\chapter{Chapter}

Some text \nomenclature{HTML}{HyperText Markup Language}

\printnomenclature
\end{document}
```

The nomenclature was generated with `makeindex test.nlo -s nomencl.ist -o test.nls` and here is the `test.nls`:

```
\begin{thenomenclature}

\nomgroup{A}

  \item [{HTML}]\begingroup HyperText Markup Language\nomeqref {0}
        \nompageref{1}
  \item [{HTML}]\begingroup HyperText Markup Language\nomeqref {1.0}
        \nompageref{3}

\end{thenomenclature}
```

Problem comes with lines at `test.nlo` are not identical:

```
\nomenclatureentry{aHTML@[{HTML}]\begingroup HyperText Markup Language\nomeqref {0}|nompageref}{1}
\nomenclatureentry{aHTML@[{HTML}]\begingroup HyperText Markup Language\nomeqref {1.0}|nompageref}{3}
```

In my real tex `\nomeqref`'s content is `\relax x.x` for duplicate entries.

Comment: I tried to use **uniq** command to _.nls_ file but each entry is not a single line but 2 lines.

Comment: You are misusing the `nomencl` package, which is made for unique entries. You probably should be using either `acronym` or the more general `glossaries` package.

Comment: You're perfectly right @egreg, acronym package fits exactly what I need. Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `nomencl` package has a different purpose than what you're using it for.

The package's purpose is to write a list of symbols or abbreviation used, with a reference to the place where they're defined or first used (at the user's choice). So it's not meant to place multiple reference to a nomenclature.

For acronyms the best package around is [`glossaries`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/glossaries), but the simpler [`acronym`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/acronym) is often used.

Answer (score 2):

I may have missed something but with the following code I get only **one** entry in the nomenclature.

```
% This is test.tex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{nomencl}
\makenomenclature
\begin{document}
Some text \nomenclature{HTML}{HyperText Markup Language}

\newpage

Some text \nomenclature{HTML}{HyperText Markup Language}

\printnomenclature

\end{document}
```

The nomenclature was generated with `makeindex test.nlo -s nomencl.ist -o test.nls` and here is the `test.nls`.

```
\begin{thenomenclature} 

 \nomgroup{A}

  \item [{HTML}]\begingroup HyperText Markup Language\nomeqref {0}
        \nompageref{1, 2}

\end{thenomenclature}
```

Comment: I edited the question because I couldn't show here commented the minimal example that generate multiple entries.

Answer (score 1):

This is a manual and not elegant post-editing workaround to `test.nls`

In kile/kate editor do replace whole text with the following regular expression:

```
Find:    (.*\[\{)(.*)\}\].*\n.*\n.*\[\{\2\}\]
Replace: \1\2\}\]
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a manual and not elegant post-editing workaround to `test.nlo`

In command line do:

```
cat test.nlo | sort | uniq -w 49 > test.nlo
```

and then:

```
makeindex test.nlo -s nomencl.ist -o test.nls
```

uniq `-w` parameter is 49 because is the width of the shortest nomenclature before differences in nomeqref `\nomenclatureentry{a@[{}]\begingroup \nomeqref {` and can handle up to 30 characters in nomenclatures.

Comment: It could be shorter: `cat test.nlo | sort | uniq -w 49 | makeindex -i -s nomencl.ist -o test.nls`