# Equation and nomenclature shortcut macros yield duplicate nomenclature entries

Tags: nomencl

I am trying to create an easy way to include a number of equations in multiple spots of a report (or reports) without having to retype them each time and keep nomenclature consistent across all equations. I have an "equation library" that I want to include in various files to make the equations available.

```
% eq.tex
\def \a {\nomenclature{$a$}{Coefficient}}
\def \b {\nomenclature{$b$}{Coefficient}}
\def \c {\nomenclature{$c$}{Coefficient}}
\def \m {\nomenclature{$m$}{Slope}}
\def \x {\nomenclature{$x$}{Variable}}
\def \y {\nomenclature{$y$}{Variable}}

\def \line {
\label{line}
\b \m \x \y
$$y=mx+b$$
}

\def \parabola {
\label{parabola}
\a \b \c \x \y
$$y=ax^2+bx+c$$
}
```

This way I can just include `\line` in a file and have the necessary nomenclature available.

```
% main.tex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{nomencl}
\makenomenclature
\input{eq}
\begin{document}
\printnomenclature

\line    
\parabola

\end{document}
```

This produces the nomenclature as you would expect

> Nomenclature
>
> a   Coefficient
>
> b   Coefficient
>
> c   Coefficient
>
> m   Slope
>
> x   Variable
>
> y   Variable

However, I would like to have an equation number and label available to reference in the text. When I introduce the `equation` environment, the nomenclature section has duplicate entries.

I've tried both

```
\begin{equation}
\line    
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
\parabola
\end{equation}
```

and

```
\def \line {
\label{line}
\b \m \x \y
\begin{equation}
y=mx+b
\end{equation}
}

\def \parabola {
\label{parabola}
\a \b \c \x \y
\begin{equation}
y=ax^2+bx+c
\end{equation}
}
```

which both yield duplicate entries in the nomenclature

> Nomenclature
>
> a   Coefficient
>
> b   Coefficient
>
> b   Coefficient
>
> c   Coefficient
>
> m   Slope
>
> x   Variable
>
> x   Variable
>
> y   Variable
>
> y   Variable

Is there something special about the `equation` environment that is throwing this off? Am I missing some fundamental understanding about defining terms?

I also tried using `\newcommand` and the document wouldn't compile

Comment: The same issue is discussed here http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/32891/nomenclature-duplicates -- However you shouldn't define commands with a single token. Some hints: In your definition `\label` has no anchor. Using of `$$` is obsolete: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/40492/what-are-the-differences-between-align-equation-and-displaymath