# Nomenclature gets shown twice, when the key is written twice: wanting only once

Tags: nomenclature, nomencl

I'm formatting documents, which will then get compiled as a final document. The problem arises when I'm working with nomenclature, each separate document has a nomenclature with a single key with a description, but when these documents get compiled, two separate documents have the same key and it gets shown twice in the final document. Is there a workaround, so that a nomenclature key gets shown only once?

By Key and Description, I mean these:

```
\nomenclature{key}{description}
```

[image: It shows the compilation]
Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Can you please show us a short compilable TeX code(s) resulting in your issue?

Comment: I am currently using comand: makeindex -s nomencl.ist -t %.nlg -o %.nls %.nlo as a user

Comment: The problem is not that it doesn't work

Comment: It just shows duplicats

Comment: Related: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/32891/nomenclature-duplicates

Comment: Thank you! The related link helped!